# React script rendering not grabbing script file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to use a script when a certain component renders but script,src is not grabbing my resource file

```
  const script = document.createElement('script');

  script.src = '../script/index.js';      // not grabbing my index.js script
  script.async = true;

  document.body.appendChild(script);

  return () => {
    document.body.removeChild(script);
  
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: It's a local file path. You should serve your script, not load it directly from your disk. Also, I'm sure React has a way to execute a function on component init (`componentDidMount`?), you don't have to do things like `createElement('script')`

Comment: Why would you want to do that? this doesnt seem like a clean way of coding. What is it you want to accomplish and why?